# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am working on asp.net 3.5 application and using googlemap control (http://en.googlemaps.subgurim.net/) but I am getting error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Component 'ctl00_Main_CPH_tbSharedPricebook' was not found.
```

Please suggest me solution to this.

Comment: <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main_CPH" runat="server">
   <cc2:GMap ID="GMap1" runat="server" /></asp:Content>

Comment: yes. I have used toolkitscriptmanager

Comment: can you paste more code by editing your question please. That would assist others for providing correct help

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if you have added any script reference more then one time on page?